# Transfer Files Between putty Sessions

Tags: ssh, putty, file-transfer

I often find myself wanting to grab a file from one Linux box for use on another. Usually this occurs when I am running Windows, and logged into SSH on both machines in separate putty SSH sessions.

I know how to copy/paste using various messy windows clipboard / putty screen grab things (for text files only); how to transfer it via scp; even how to use rsync remote copying. But these are all a pita, error prone, and often require opening firewall ports etc.

Is there a simple way to move a whole file from one putty session to another without lots of hassle? (I know putty is text-only, but in Windows all this takes is dragging from one Explorer window to another. Can't putty be as straightforward?)

Comment: Use Notepad or like as an intermediary.  Copy, paste into text editor, next system, copy, paste into putty

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do now. But the only way I know how to copy the file is to do a cat in putty and then capture the whole session into the Windows copy / paste buffer. Then I have to delete everything that is isn't the file before recopying everything into the target putty session. Hardly simple, and very error-prone.